# Bash script for basic mathematic operations

Tags: linux, bash, math

I am new to Linux, and I just want a Bash Script to do basic arithmetic operation  to a text file

```
1
2
3  
4
```

and the results should be addition and multiplication in separate text files

say add + 5 for 1st text file and mult * 5 in 2nd text file

```
add:                             mult: 
6                                5
7                                10
8                                15
9                                20
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything here? See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for how to properly and safely read lines from a file in bash/the shell. Though you could also do what you want with `awk` or `perl` or similar instead of the shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This reads each number from the input file, and outputs the correctly modified output to each output file.

```
while IFS='' read -r number; do
    printf "%d\n" $((number + 5)) >&3
    printf "%d\n" $((number * 5)) >&4
done < input.txt 3> first.txt 4> second.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try awk.

```
 awk '{print $1,  $1*5}' file.txt
```

Will print the results in the standard output which you can redirect to a file.

An easy way to separate the results:

```
 awk '{print $1+5 > "add.txt";  print $1*5 > "mul.txt"}' file.txt
```

Comment: The OP asks to do these in separate files.

Comment: @CommuSoft You are right! I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. `while IFS= read -r num; do echo "$((num+5))" ; done < filename`
2. `while IFS= read -r num; do echo "$((num*5))" ; done < filename`

Comment: Nor with `cat` ("*useless use of `cat`*").

Answer (score 0):

you can user below command

```
awk '{print $1+1}' file.txt  > add.txt
awk '{print $1*5}' file.txt  > malti.txt
```